# Logical AND in a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

I want to add an additional condition in the `for` loop.

```
for(i=1; (i<100)&&(something>0.001) ; i++)
{
   //do something
}
```

How can I implement this in MATLAB?

The following isn't working:

```
for (y = 1:pI_present_y) && (max_sim_value > threshold)
    % do something
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [`for`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop, the number of iterations and the values that the loop variable will have in those iterations are selected as soon as it is executed the first time.
Since you want to check the condition on every iteration, you cannot use a `for` loop without introducing an [`if`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) condition inside the loop. This is what [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478826/5698672) by [souty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7862136/souty).

However, it would be better to use [`break`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) once the condition is not satisfied. In this way it will be a true replica of the C code. Otherwise the loop will keep executing till `y` equals `pI_present_y`. The result will be same but there will be unnecessary iterations and the value of the loop variable will be different at the end of the loop. i.e.

```
for y = 1:pI_present_y-1  %Subtracting 1 because you have i<100 in the C code, not i<=100
    if max_sim_value <= threshold
       break;
    end
    %do something
end
```

If you want to use that condition in the loop statement, it is only possible with a [`while`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) loop.

```
y=1;
while(y<pI_present_y   &&   max_sim_value>threshold)
    % do something
    y=y+1;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Logical conditions are expressed in `if` statements

```
for (y = 1:pI_present_y)
    if (max_sim_value > threshold)
        % do something
    end
end
```

If one of `max_sim_value` and `threshold` is a vector of length `pI_present_y`, index it with `y` in the `if` statement, i.e. `max_sim_value(y)` or `threshold(y)`.